# C: creating an archive file header

Tags: c

I am creating a file archiver/extractor (like tar), using POSIX API system calls in C. I have done part of the archiving bit.

I would like to know if any one could help me with some C source code (using above) to create a  file header for a file in C (where header acts as an index), which describes the files attributes/meta data (name,date time,etc).  All I have done so far is understand (not sure if that's even correct) that to create a file header it needs
a struct to hold the meta data, and lseek is needed to seek to beginning/end of file
like:

> FileName=file.txt FileSize=0
>
> FileDir=./blah/blah
>
> FilePerms=000
>
> \n\n

The archiving part of program has this process:

1. Get a list of all the files from the command line. (I can do this part)
2. Create a structure to hold the meta data about each file: name (255 char), size (64-bit int), date and time, and permissions.
3. For each file, get its stats.
4. Store the stats of each file within an array of structures.
5. Open the archive for writing. (I can do this part)
6. Write the header structure.
7. For each file, append its content to the archive file (at the end/start of each file).
8. Close the archive file. (I can do this part)

I am having difficulty in creating the header file as a whole even though I know what it needs to do, as mentioned in numbered points above the bits I cant do are stated (2,3,4,6,7).

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You may want to edit this to make it clear *much* earlier (like in the title) that you are talking about a "*file header*" not a "*header file*". In the context of the C programming language, the latter has a specific meaning unrelated to your usage of the term.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [ijw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87583/ijw) notes, there are several ways to create an archive file header.  If cross-platform portability is going to be an issue at all - or if you need to switch between 32-bit and 64-bit builds of the software on the same platform, even - then you need to ensure that the sizes and layouts of the fields are fully understood on all platforms.

#### Per-file Metadata

One way to do that is to use a fixed format binary header with types of known size and endianness.  This is what ijw suggested.  However, you will need to handle long file names, and so you will need to store a length (probably in a 2-byte unsigned integer) and then follow that with the actual pathname.

The alternative, and generally now favoured technique, is to use printable fields (often called ASCII format, though that is something of a misnomer).  The time is recorded as the decimal number of seconds since the Epoch converted to a string, etc.  This is what modern `ar` archives use; it is what GNU `tar` does (more or less; there are some historical quirks that make that more confusing); it is what `cpio -c` (which is usually the default these days) does.  The fields might be separated by nulls or spaces; there is an easy way to detect the end of the header; the header contains information about the file name (not necessarily as directly as you'd like or expect, but again, that is usually because the format has evolved over the years), and then is followed by the actual data.  Somehow, you know the size of each field, and the file which the header describes, so that you can read the data reliably.

Efficiency is a red herring.  The conversion to/from the text format is so swift by comparison with the first disk access that there is essentially no measurable performance issue.  And the guaranteed portability typically far outweighs the (microscopic) performance benefit from using binary data format instead - doubly so when the binary data has to be transformed on input or output anyway to get it into an architecture-neutral format.

#### Central Index vs Distributed Index

The other issue to consider is whether the index of files in the archive is centralized (at the front, or at the end) or distributed (the metadata for each file immediately precedes the data for the file).  There are some advantages to each format - generally, systems use the distributed version because you can write the information for each file without knowing how many files there are to process in total (for example, because you are recursively archiving a directory's contents).  Having a central index up front means you can list the files without reading the whole archive - distributed metadata means you have to read the whole file.  However, the central index complicates the building of the archive.

Note that even with a distributed index, you will normally need a header for the archive as a whole so that you can detect that the file is in the format you expect.  Typically, there is some sort of marker information (`!<arch>\n` for an `ar` archive, usually; `%PDF-1.2\n` at the start of a PDF file, etc) to reassure you that the file contains what you expect.  There might be some overall (archive-level) metadata.  Then you will have the first file metadata followed by the file data, repeating until the end of archive (which might, or might not, have a formal end marker - more metadata).

---

> [H]ow would I go about implementing it in the 'fixed format binary header' you suggested. I am having trouble with deciding what commands/functions are needed.

I intended to suggest that you do not go with a fixed format binary header; you should use a text-based header format.  If you can work out how to do the binary format, be my guest (I've done it numerous times over the years - that doesn't mean I think it is a good idea).

So, some pointers here towards the 'text header' format.

For the file metadata, you might define that you include:

- size
- mode (permissions, type)
- owner
- group
- modification time
- length of name
- name

You might reasonably decide that your file sizes are limited to 64-bit unsigned integer quantities, which means 20 decimal digits.  The mode might be printed as a 16-bit octal number, requiring 6 octal digits.  The owner and group might be printed as UID and GID values (rather than name), in which case you could use 10 digits for each.  Alternatively, you could decide to use names, but you should then allow for names up to say 32 characters each.  Note that names are typically more portable than numbers.  Neither name nor number is of much relevance on the receiving machine unless you extract the data as root (but why would you want to do that?).  The modification time is classically a 32-bit signed integer, representing the number of seconds since the Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00Z).  You should allow for the Y2038 bug by allowing the number of seconds to grow bigger than the 32-bit quantity; you might decide that 12 leading digits will take you beyond the Y10K crisis (by a factor of 4 or so), and this is good enough; you might decide to allow for fractional seconds too.  Together, this suggests that 26 spaces for the timestamp should be overkill.  You can decide that each field will be separated from the next by a space (for legibility - think 'ease of debugging'!).  You might reasonably decide that all file names will be restricted to 4 decimal digits in total length.

You need to know how to format the types portably - `#include <inttypes.h>` is your friend.

You then devise a format string for printing (writing) the file metadata, and a parallel string for scanning (reading) the file metadata.

Printing:

```
"%20" PRIu64 " %06o %-.32s %-.32s %26" PRIu64 " %-4d %s\n"
```

This prints the name too.  It terminates the header with a newline. The total size is 127 bytes plus the length of the file name.  That's probably excessive, but you can tweak the numbers to suit yourself.

Scanning:

```
"%" SCNu64 " %o %.32s %.32s %" SCNu64 "%d"
```

This does not scan the name; you need to create the scanner for the name carefully, not least because you need to read spaces in the name.  In fact, the code for scanning the user name and group name both assume no spaces too.  If that is not acceptable (that is, names may contain spaces), then you need a more complex scan format, or something other than `sscanf()` to process the input data.

I'm assuming a 64-bit integer for the time field, rather than mixing up fractional seconds, etc, even though there's enough space to allow for fractional seconds.  You'd likely save some space here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how would I go about implementing it in the 'fixed format binary header' you suggested, I am having trouble with deciding what commands/functions are needed, I understand the logic more now, but applying this logic is difficult(sorry i am not so strong in programming yet).

Answer (score 4):

The getting of information for each file you can do with the stat() system call.

For the writing of the header, here's two solutions.

Trivial but evil:

```
struct file_header {
... data you want to put in 
} fhdr;

fwrite(file, fhdr, sizeof(fhdr));
```

This is evil because structure packing varies from machine to machine, as does byte order and the size of basic types like 'int'.  A file written by your program may not be readable by your program when it's compiled on another machine, or even with another compiler on the same machine in some cases.

Non-trivial but safe:

```
char name[xxx];
uint32_t length; /* Fixed byte length across architectures */
...

fwrite(file, name, sizeof(name));
length=htonl(length); /* Or something else that converts 
                         the length to a known endianness */
fwrite(file, &length, sizeof(length);
```

Personally I'm not a fan of htonl() and friends, I prefer to write something that converts a uint32_t to a uchar[4] using shift operators (which can be written trivially using shift operators) because C doesn't pin down the format of even an integer in memory.  In practice you'd be hard pushed to find something that doesn't store a uint32_t as 4 bytes of 8 bits, but it's a thing to consider.

The variables listed above can be structure members in your structure.  Reversing the process on read is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks for your help , I have created something similar to the trivial example, will give them a go.